# How to reinstate ClipCursor constriction after alt-tab switching away and back

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to restrict the mouse pointer (with a custom cursor) to the client area of the window for my app which works initially but runs into problems when I switch away from the app and back. I'm using `ClipCursor()` to restrict the cursor and using a couple of different cursors which are situation dependant so I'm using `SetCursor()` instead of setting the window's class cursor.

I've got the cursor reinstating itself correctly when Alt-Tabbing away from the app and back (which I want to allow) by checking for the WM_SETCURSOR message in my WndProc:

```
case WM_SETCURSOR:
{
    if (mIsMouseGrabOn)  // a bool that indicates if the mouse should be restricted to the cient area or not
        SetCursor(gmInstance->m_cursorTargetGreen);
    else
        SetCursor(gmInstance->m_cursorTargetRed);
    return 0; // prevent DefWndProc from resetting it
}
```

but on switching back the cursor is no longer clipped to the client area of my app's window. I've tried checking for WM_ACTIVATEAPP (as shown below) with no luck and tried checking for WM_ACTIVATE with the same code and the same result.

```
case WM_ACTIVATEAPP:
{
    if(wParam == TRUE) // When we are activated
    { 
        if (mIsMouseGrabOn)
            GrabMouse(); // function to determine client area and call ClipCusor with the results
        else
            ClipCusor(NULL); // make the sure cursor is freed
    }
    else if(wParam == FALSE) // When we are deactivated
    {
        ClipCursor(NULL);
    }
    //return 0; // Let DefWndProc handle anything else
}
```

With the above code in place, the cursor changes correctly but doesn't get captured regardless of the state of `mIsMouseGrabOn`.

How do I get my cursor to be bound correctly when switching away from the app and back? What message(s) should I be watching for instead of WM_ACTIVATEAPP?

Answer (score 2):

You can watch lost focus and got focus messages

1) WA_ACTIVE or WA_CLICKACTIVE - window got focus

2) WA_INACTIVE - window lost focus

and you should watch if your app run in fullscreen mode:

3) WM_DISPLAYCHANGE - when Windows changing desktop resolution

and resize message

WM_SIZE - if wparam equals SIZE_MINIMIZED,SIZE_MAXIMIZED or SIZE_RESTORED you can clip or unclip cursor

Answer (score 0):

`WM_SETFOCUS` is sent after the Window receives keyboard focus, which allows ClipCursor to work.